# Why am I getting 'Authentication required' error when sending email in Android .NET MAUI?

Tags: security, connection, system.net, system.net.mail

I am having this error when sending an email from the android App in .Net MAUI Version 6.0, before my code was working perfectly but now it is giving the error said:**Error sending email: The AMTP server requires a secure connection or client was not authenticated. the server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required** But when i try to run the project in windows the code is working perfectly but in android it's failing.

```
public void Mail(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add("example@gmail.com");// replace with the recipient email address
        message.From = new MailAddress("example@gmail.com");// replace with the sender email address
        message.Subject = "Black Soldier Fly Farming Repport";
        message.Body = "My Body";

        // create a new attachment from a file
        var attachment = new Attachment(filePath);

        // add the attachment to the email message
        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        using (var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
        {
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("example@gmail.com", "examplePass");
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Timeout = 5000;
            client.Send(message);
            DisplayAlert($"Uploading Repport:", "Repport Submitted!", "Okay");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle any errors that occur
        DisplayAlert($"Error sending email:", ex.Message, "Okay");
    }
}
```